# How do timeouts work in Hystrix with Observables?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rx-java, hystrix

I'm working on a Hystrix-enabled Spring Boot-app using Reactive Observables and trying to figure out how timeouts works. I assumed that if a timeout happened during execution, Hystrix would immediately return a response (fallback or exception). Now this seems not to be the case given my code below. Instead the call to `myService.getString()` blocks for 5 secs. When it finally returns, the throwable lambda is executed.

Are my assumptions incorrect or is something else wrong below?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
}

@RestController
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public DeferredResult index() {

    DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    Observable<String> res = myService.getString();

    res.subscribe(s -> {
                result.setResult("Got a " + s);
            },
            throwable -> {
                result.setErrorResult("Got a " + throwable.getMessage());
            });

    return result;
  }
}


@Service
public class MyService {

  @HystrixCommand() // Default timeout is 1 sec
  public Observable<String> getString() {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            subscriber.onNext("regular response");
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

pom.xml:
    
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>dag</groupId>
    <artifactId>dag</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
            <artifactId>hystrix-javanica</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify what's the isolation of your hystrix command and what hystrix version did you use?

> "Timeouts now apply to semaphore-isolated commands as well as
>   thread-isolated commands. Before 1.4.x, semaphore-isolated commands
>   could not timeout. They now have a timeout registered on another
>   (HystrixTimer) thread, which triggers the timeout flow. If you use
>   semaphore-isolated commands, they will now see timeouts"

Anyway try to:

1. Switch to THREAD isolation with own thread pool.
2. Sleep in cycle with smaller periods.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The default is THREAD isolation level, so I'm using this.

Comment: Ok... The default seems to be SEMAPHORE, and not THREAD as stated in the docs: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution

Answer (score 0):

Setting `execution.isolation.strategy` to `THREAD` solves my issue.

```
@HystrixCommand(
  commandProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "THREAD")
  }
)
```

The docs states that `HystrixCommand` defaults to using `THREAD` but it's a bit different for javanica `@HystrixCommand` which creates different types depending on the annotated method's return type. `HystrixCommand` or `HystrixObservableCommand`. And `HystrixObservableCommand` has `SEMAPHORE`as default isolation strategy.

See https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1383 for more details.